# When is a pending signal no longer considered pending?

Tags: c, operating-system

I'm reading about signals and I read that a signal that has been sent but not received is considered `pending`. Additionally, control jumps to a handler whenever a OS does a context switch to some process and discovers a `pending` and `unblocked` signal.

When is the bit for a signal in the pending bitmask cleared? Is it only when the handler finishes processing the signal? Or is it cleared the moment control jumps to the beginning of the handler?

I'm curious because I'm not sure what happens if for example, a `SIGINT` signal arrived while a `SIGINT` handler was already processing the signal and chose not to block further `SIGINT` signals. (I read that by default, signal handlers for signal K will block signal K by default but I'm wondering what happens if it is unblocked)

Comment: The `SIGINT` issue does not only depend on how long a signal is pending, but also whether the handler remains active once it had processed a signal. E.g.: See `signal` vs. `sigaction`. Also I'm afraid there is no "cross-system answer" for this question as some semantics vary over systems (i.e.: "Unspecified" in general).

Comment: _what happens if for example, a SIGINT signal arrived while a SIGINT handler was already processing_ : For interruptible functions, it will generally depend on the flag sets for the signal (see [SA_RESTART flag](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html)  for example).